# Is there a closed form for $\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \sqrt[k] n$ for some natural number $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As titled. I'm still thinking about this question. Thanks for any discussions on this!

Comment: Intuitively, your number can quite accurately be approximated as just $\sqrt n$.

Comment: @guest The sum overshoots square root of n by quite a bit

Comment: I think there's a field theory theorem that looks like "$\alpha_1^{1/\gamma_1}+\alpha_2^{1/\gamma_2}+...+\alpha_n^{1/\gamma_n}$ generates $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1^{1/\gamma_1}, \alpha_2^{1/\gamma_2}, ..., \alpha_n^{1/\gamma_n})$" when all the $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ satisfies some condition...

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't noticed that the number has $n-1$ terms so it should be at least $n-1$

Comment: @guest. The sum is larger than $(n-1) n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: An exact formula seems uncanny. As to asymptotics, for any fixed $k$, we have $$x_n = n + x_k + \mathcal{O}_k(n^{\frac{1}{k+1}})$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

(*Too long for a comment*.) $\;x_n=\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \sqrt[k] n\,$ is an algebraic number whose minimal polynomial can be explicitly determined, but is unlikely to be solvable in a "*closed form*" any simpler or more general than the sum that originally defined it. First few cases:

- $n=2\,$: $\;x_2=\sqrt{2}\,$ satisfies $\;x^2-2=0$
- $n=3\,$: $\;x_3\,$ satisfies [$\;x^6 - 9 x^4 - 6 x^3 + 27 x^2 - 54 x - 18=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+surd(3,2)%2Bsurd(3,3))
- $n=4\,$: $\;x_4\,$ satisfies [$\;x^6 - 12 x^5 + 54 x^4 - 120 x^3 + 156 x^2 - 192 x + 184=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+surd(4,2)%2Bsurd(4,3)%2Bsurd(4,4))
- $n=5\,$: $\;x_5\,$ satisfies a [$60^{th}$ degree polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+surd(5,2)%2Bsurd(5,3)%2Bsurd(5,4)%2Bsurd(5,5))

Comment: For each individual $n$, $\sum_{k=2}^n \sqrt[k]{n} = n^{1/2} + n^{1/3} + \ldots + n^{1/n}$ is a "closed form".  It is unlikely that there is a single "closed form" that works for all $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Fair point, thanks. I edited my answer to (hopefully) make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether a closed form exists but using Jensen's inequality we can derive a lower bound as follows.

Let $X$ be a random variable with sample space $\left\{2, 3, \ldots, n \right\}$ and with probability $P(X=i) = \frac{1}{n-1}$. Let $g(x) = n^{\frac{1}{x}}$ which is a convex function when $x>0$. By Jensen's inequality,

$$Eg(X) \geq g(EX)$$

$$\implies \frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}n^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n-1} \geq g\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}k}{n-1}\right) = g\left(\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1}{n-1}\right) = g\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right) = n^{\frac{2}{n+2}}$$

$$\implies \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}n^{\frac{1}{k}} \geq (n-1)n^{\frac{2}{n+2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

No.

But notice

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n} n^{\frac{1}{k}-1} = 1$$

being equal to

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{2}^x x^{\frac{1}{y}-1} {d}y$$

This second is simpler to evaluate, although even that on its own does not have a closed form without using exponential or similar integral.